# how to override windows back button in windows phone 8 ?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to ovveride the windows back button when i am clicking from my application .I tried 2 method below but it is not working in windows phone 8  ?

methods 1)

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)

            {

           e.Cancel = true;

           var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Attention!",
                                      MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
           // base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
            return;
        }
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

method 2 )

a) wrote this in xaml heading

```
BackKeyPress="MyBackKeyPress"
```

b) Initlize this in constructor

```
 BackKeyPress += OnBackKeyPress;
```

c) and call this method

```
   private void MyBackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; //tell system you have handled it
        //you c
    }
```

the two of the methods are not working . when i was clicked the back button the app destroyed and unable to get the control of backbutton . Any help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per certification requirements it is not recommended to override the back button -

> Pressing the Back button from the first screen of an app must close
>   the app.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

You can try this code

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?","Confirm Exit?", 
                            MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; 

    }
}
```

Comment: yes i put the code not in the starting page . And this is not working . i am using emulator for testing .

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? crash?

Comment: app is exiting without any exception and not crashing.

Comment: i create a new then the above code is working . but why the ovveride is not woking in the present app . any idea ?

Comment: hmm can you try debugging without adding any code, override should work. Try closing the IDE and reopen. Also un-install the app from emulator and try debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, which works for me

Step 1 : in XAML

```
BackKeyPress="PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress"
```

Step 2 : in C#

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBoxResult mRes = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (mRes == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
            if (mRes == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried the same . but it is not working . i put the breakpoints inside the code and also found its not entering or not calling the function when i click back button .

Comment: yes , i got the solution from [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397163/what-is-the-hype-around-the-windows-phone-8-back-button [link]  ... its the problem related to (5.2.4.3) context path .. thanks  ..

Answer (score 1):

In your `MyBackKeyPress` method, throw a new exception to close the app in the runtime and return to the phone's menu. I don't know if this is a good way to achieve it, but this definitely solves the problem.

```
private void MyBackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     throw new Exception();
}
```

Test this on emulator/device without `Dubugging`in `Visual Studio` and you will see that your app closes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same . but it is not working . i put the breakpoints inside the code and also found its not entering or not calling the function when i click back button . – user1703145 45 mins ago

You haven't forgotten to bind this event in XAML?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ..... BackKeyPress="phoneApplicationPage_BackKeyPress">
```

Comment: you added it manually or automaticaly via Events Properties? MAybe try doing it automatically if you done it manually?

Comment: i tried both methods . i give the ovverride method in the same page that i am clicking . Is any relation this with the navigation or events . I am navigation to the next page like this              Page3 obj= new Page3(data.message_id);
this.Content = obj;

Comment: yes , i got the solution from [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397163/what-is-the-hype-around-the-windows-phone-8-back-button [link]  ... its the problem related to (5.2.4.3) context path .. thanks  ..