# Close App Confirmation using MessageDialog for Windows Phone 8.1 using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I've got a problem with the **Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog** class. The thing is: 
I want to ask the user if (s) he wants to close the app, when clicking the back button (on the first **Page**). I've tried two approaches: 
First is setting the BackPressed method **async**:

```
private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog logout = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Do You want to close the app?");
    logout.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Yes", Exit));
    logout.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("No"));
    await logout.ShowAsync();
}
```

Second is using the **System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAny(...)** method:

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog logout = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Do You want to close the app?");
    logout.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Yes", Exit));
    logout.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("No"));
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAny(logout.ShowAsync().AsTask());
}
```

What I get is: 
First: the MessageDialog shows just for a sec, then app minimizes, switching to it, and pressing the back button, just minimizes app again, but **MessageDialog** is not shown).
Second: it's a deadlock (after clicking "Yes", **MessageDialog** closes, but the **Exit()** method is not called, app freezes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to override windows back button in windows phone 8 ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479578/how-to-override-windows-back-button-in-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

**Microsoft recommends that apps not close themselves programmatically.**

See here:

[App lifecycle - Windows app development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx#close)

That page says:

> You can't include any UI in your app to enable the user to close your app, or it won't pass the Store certification process.

Although I know that there are apps in the Store that do this anyway.

---

Anyway, in the `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` event handler, `e.Handled = true;` is needed to prevent the app from closing.  This also applies for when navigating backwards in your app.

Besides this, `Frame.CanGoBack` should be checked to see if the app should navigate or close.

Also, you should not need to use a task, but just await `MessageDialog.ShowAsync()`, although you could create a task that returns a boolean telling whether to proceed or not.

---

Here is an entire code example to use that handles navigating backwards in the frame stack and displays a message dialog asking whether to close the app or not when the first frame is reached:

App.xaml.cs:

```
using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

public sealed partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }

    private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (frame == null) { return; }
        e.Handled = true;
        if (frame.CanGoBack) { frame.GoBack(); return; }
        else
        {
            string content = "Do you want to close the app?";
            string title = "Close Confirmation";
            MessageDialog confirmDialog = new MessageDialog(content, title);
            confirmDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes"));
            confirmDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No"));
            var confirmResult = await confirmDialog.ShowAsync();
            // "No" button pressed: Keep the app open.
            if (confirmResult != null && confirmResult.Label == "No") { return; }
            // "Back" or "Yes" button pressed: Close the app.
            if (confirmResult == null || confirmResult.Label == "Yes") { Current.Exit(); }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thx a lot :) The thing was just missing "e.Handled = true;" statement.

Comment: Yes, and I thought that to make it a very good answer I would give a thorough explanation in case it could help others.